# Responsive design for mobile only, not desktop

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a site that will be responsive on mobile devices but not on desktop computers.

I created a media query with the following breaking points: 320px, 321-480px, 481-680px, 681-778px, 779-1280px. The problem is that these apply to resized browsers on desktop computers too and display the mobile version. I want it to ignore these breaking points and display the desktop version of my site regardless of window size.

Is this possible? Thank you very much for an answer!

Comment: Please post your affected code

Comment: I feel like you might be approaching responsive web design from the wrong angle. You should not be forcing a desktop version of a site on a 400px width device/window. The best responsive websites fit all screen sizes nicely, that's the point of RWD.

Comment: I think that it's the whole point of responsive design .. to load whatever you have set for those breakpoints depending on your device's width. It sounds like you'd rather have a device-dependent site rather than width-dependent

Comment: I don't get your point. Please post your code: at least CSS code, and JavaScript if you have any JS related to viewport size. The point of media queries is: adapt the website layout to the **window size**, not to the device. So if you resize your window, it's normal that the layout change, and you see the exact same thing on mobile that on desktop with a small-width window.

Comment: I have allot of code here I realy don't know what to post! It's also hard to explain my problem. Sorry I shoudn't ask in the first place.

Comment: Define “desktop”. It’s harder than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make a lot of since to make a responsive site that is only responsive for mobile. Maybe use a server side script for device detection  and make two separate sites for mobile and desktop.